# Degrees minutes seconds to radians formula not working

Tags: java, math, degrees, radians

Here is the code:

```
double r = Double.parseDouble(radius.getText().toString());
                double del = Double.parseDouble(delta.getText().toString());


                double dm = ((int)((del - ((int)del)) * 100));

                double rads = (((int)del) + (dm / 60) + (((((del - ((int)del)) * 100) - ((int)((del - ((int)del)) * 100))) * 100) / 3600)) * (Math.PI / 180);

                String t = String.valueOf(r * (Math.tan(rads / 2)));
                String c = String.valueOf(2* r* (Math.sin((rads/2))));
                String m = String.valueOf(r*(1- Math.cos((rads/2))));
                String a = String.valueOf(2*Math.PI*r*((((int)del) + (dm / 60) + (((((del - ((int)del)) * 100) - ((int)((del - ((int)del)) * 100))) * 100) / 3600))/360));

                tangent.setText(t);
                arc.setText(a);
                chord.setText(c);
                mid.setText(m);
```

My objective is to reduce the number of variables I am using in my program to clean it up a bit.  As it sits the way I have posted it, the formulas work.  If I replace "dm" in the double "rads" with the current value of "((int)((del - ((int)del)) * 100))",  the formulas no longer work.  It has something to do with the "/60".  I've tried different bracket situations and just doesn't seem to work.  I have replaced the "dm" in other parts of the formula and it all still works, its just in that one location.  Any ideas?

Comment: As an example I will use 60d25'25'', the "dm/60 is supposed to convert the 25' into decimal degrees...so it would equal 0.416666666

Comment: What language? Also fix the code formatting in the post.

Comment: The language is Java, I am creating an android app.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is hard to read.  That's part of the reason why you're struggling.

I'd write it this way:

```
package misc;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 12/12/2015.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236175/degrees-minutes-seconds-to-radians-formula-not-working
 */
public class AngleConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double degrees = (args.length > 0) ? Double.valueOf(args[0]) : 0.0;
        double minutes = (args.length > 1) ? Double.valueOf(args[1]) : 0.0;
        double seconds = (args.length > 2) ? Double.valueOf(args[2]) : 0.0;
        double radians = convertDegreesToRadians(degrees, minutes, seconds);
        System.out.println(String.format("degrees: %10.6f", degrees));
        System.out.println(String.format("minutes: %10.6f", minutes));
        System.out.println(String.format("seconds: %10.6f", seconds));
        System.out.println(String.format("radians: %10.6f", radians));
        System.out.println(String.format("degrees: %10.6f", Math.toDegrees(radians)));

    }

    public static double convertDegreesToRadians(double degrees, double minutes, double seconds) {
        double angle = degrees + minutes/60.0 + seconds/3600.0;
        return Math.toRadians(angle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `d m s` degrees, minutes and seconds. Given that

```
60 minutes = 1 degree
60 seconds = 1 minute
```

we get that the total number of degrees represented by `d m s` is

```
deg = d + m/60 + s/60^2
```

Now it is a matter of converting `deg` degrees to radians. But

```
360 degrees = 2*Pi radians
```

So,

```
1 degrees = (2*Pi/360) radians
```

and

```
deg degrees = deg * (2*Pi/360) radians
```

Summarizing, the answer is

```
(d + m/60 + s/60^2) * 2 * Pi / 360
```

Which can be rewritten as

```
((s/60 + m)/60 + d)/60 * Pi/3
```

Comment: The formula I am using does work.  As a surveyor using a calculator we normally input a DMS input as dd.mmss.  The way I have it is the way I take the string "dd.mmss" and convert it to "dd.dddd" and then into radians.

Comment: the "dm" in my equation is equal to your "m" value and I am trying to divide it by 60.  But when i substitue my "double dm = ((int)((del - ((int)del)) * 100))" into where it says "dm" in the "double rads" the formula no longer works.  Which makes no sense.